# Binding dataset to ComboBox

Tags: c#, xml, data-binding, combobox

As I am getting `dataRawView` instead value in `combobox`, I was wondering is it possible to bind this `dataset` to `combobox`(`cbMissAtt`)?

What am I missing? I read many answers on this but couldn't find my way through it (as I understood I am missing to set DisplayMember but I don't know how to do it for this particular example).

p.s. I found this code somewhere as I am trying to populate cb from `xml` for the first time.

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Root");

        dt.Columns.Add("text");
        dt.Columns.Add("value");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
           dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
        }
        //after I am reading and later closing stream
         //part of code is missing because I think
         //its not relevant for the question/answer(hopefully)
         cbMissAtt.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Very simple `xml`:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Root>
        <Field text="text.." value="dedication"></Field>
        </Root>
```

I am calling this method in the form's `constructor`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code below:

```
cbMissAtt.DataBindings.Clear();
cbMissAtt.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
cbMissAtt.DisplayMember = "value";
cbMissAtt.ValueMember = "text";
```

this should show the values under `value` column unless you have a problem with your `dataset` code.

Comment: this doesnt work in my case :( I think dataset is ok : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6233/Populating-a-drop-down-control-from-an-XML-file .

Comment: Then the problem lies in the DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

in xml file instead of `<field></field>` (beginner's mistake :) ) :

```
<text>sometext</text>
<value>somevalue</value>
```

added in code too:

```
cbMissAtt.DisplayMember = "value";
cbMissAtt.ValueMember = "text";
```

thanks to P. Pat !

Comment: Good job! Glad you found the answer to your problem.